# Why is my image embedded in .md not displayed on Github

Tags: github, png, r-markdown

Assume, you have have the following Rmd (see [../Christoph999/Test/blob/master/test.md](https://github.com/Christoph999/Test/blob/master/test.md)

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Myname"
date: "5 April 2019"
output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '2'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

text

![Some text here.](../project/pics/myimage.png?raw=true){width=400px}

text
````

I pushed everything to github with pictures in `/project/pics/` (the .md file is in `/project`. But images are not displayed when I view the .md file. When I move the mouse over the caption it says

```
https://github.com/user/project/blob/project/pics/myimage.png?raw=true
```

What does the `blob/` appear? When running from RStudio, everything looks fine. I'd really appreciate, if that works. (I use Firefox)

**Edit** The folder structure looks like

```
/project  
  /.git
  /pics  
    *myimage.png  
  * Rmd
```

and `../project/pics/myimage.png` should point to the correct place?

Comment: You need to put the pictures into the relevant directory (the rmarkdown is just making the <img> tags)

Comment: @RichardTelford See my edit. I don't understand as I (think I) reference to the correct `folder/myimage.png`? What do you mean?

Comment: @RichardTelford I added a reproducible example in my github repo. See link in the beginning of my question.

Comment: problem seems to be with the ".../project". Delete this and all is fine - see pull request

Comment: @RichardTelford So easy! I just tried the wrong path variants. If you write an answer, I'll accept. (and the first time I had a pull request on Guthub ;-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank's to @richard Telfor, the solution is

```
text

![Some text here.](pics/myimage.png?raw=true){width=400px}

text
```

Be careful: The code does NOT work with pdf, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55595569/5784831)