# Why does Rmd not render to pdf while html is fine

Tags: r-markdown

If I render the following file to html, everything works.
If I render to pdf, it throws the error

> output file: test.knit.md
>   ! LaTeX Error: Unknown graphics extension: .png?raw=true.
>   Fehler: Failed to compile test.tex. See test.log for more info.

The reason is, that the Rmd is translated to

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4.16667in]{pics/myimage.png?raw=true}
\caption{Some text here.}
\end{figure}
```

in test.tex and above code does not make sense of course.
**Example:**

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Myname"
date: "5 April 2019"
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '2'
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

text

![Some text here.](pics/myimage.png?raw=true){width=400px}

text
````

I need the `?raw=TRUE` for github, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55543700/why-is-my-image-embedded-in-md-not-displayed-on-github).
You can also clone the example from [here](https://github.com/Christoph999/Test/blob/master/test.md)!

**Edit**: I also asked the developers [here](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/1702#issue-431454722), because I have the feeling, something goes wrong with `keep_md: yes`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can condition the image path on the output format via `knitr::is_html_output()`, e.g.,

````
---
title: "Untitled"
author: "Myname"
date: "5 April 2019"
output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: 2
    self_contained: false
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: yes
    toc: yes
    toc_depth: '2'
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

text

```{r, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
cat(
  '![Some text here.](pics/myimage.png',
  if (knitr::is_html_output()) '?raw=true',
  '){width=400px}',
  sep = ''
)
```

text
````

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following workaround:

1. In your `.rmd` remove the part `?raw=true`.
2. After knitting to *html*: Read the html file into R, replace `.png` with `.png?raw=true` and store it again:

You can use the following code:

```
html <- readLines("your-file.html")
html <- sapply(html, function(x) gsub(".png", ".png?raw=true", x))
writeLines(html, "your-file.html")
```

Like that you have the `?raw=true` annotation in your html file (where they belong) and not in the `.tex` file (and the `.pdf`) where they don't have a meaning.